# Service references to my wcf services issue with client objects, don't have open/close in interface?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, nunit, moq

Trying to unit test my asp.net mvc 2 controllers, and having an issue mocking my wcf client code.

My interfaces for the wcf services dont' have open/close so I can do this:

```
IMyServiceClient client = new MyServiceClient();
```

And as a result it is harder to mock (moq) this class.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Why is it harder to mock the class?

Answer (score 2):

The reason `IMyServiceClient` doesn't have Open & Close methods is that `MyServiceClient` inherits from  the `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<T>` class. `ClientBase<T>` implements the `ICommunicationObject` interface which provides those methods. Mock this class by configuring it for mocking [multiple interfaces (`IMyServiceClient` and `ICommunicationObject`).](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/08/the-joy-of-moq-multiple-interfaces/)